# Convert a Type to a Generic constrained T

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting, factory-pattern

I am trying to build a Factory which will supply a single factory method.
In this method I want to verify whether the incoming Type is the factory's T.

What I've written is simply not working. I believe I understand the reason for it's failure, yet I am not sure how to form my casting correctly.

Below is my code. Any ideas as for how to form this condition/casting?

```
    public T GetFeature(Type i_FeatureType, User i_UserContext)
    {
        T typeToGet = null;

        if (i_FeatureType is T) // <--condition fails here
        {
            if (m_FeaturesCollection.TryGetValue(i_FeatureType, out typeToGet))
            {
                typeToGet.LoggenInUser = i_UserContext;
            }
            else
            {
                addTypeToCollection(i_FeatureType as T, i_UserContext);
                m_FeaturesCollection.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out typeToGet);
                typeToGet.LoggenInUser = i_UserContext;
            }
        }

        return typeToGet;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
 if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(i_FeatureType))
```

Instead of:

```
if (i_FeatureType is T)
```

Comment: Although given that `i_FeatureType` is being used to get a value from a dictionary, maybe simple equality would be more appropriate.

Comment: Working! Thank you! It appears to be that I've misused the casting in my addTypeToCollection method as well, I will try to follow your lead in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing your objects with a 'Type' object.

So, instead of

if (i_FeatureType is T)

try

if (i_FeatureType == typeof(T))